# Creating Spring Web Application: Steps?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I am creating a simple web application using Spring MVC and Spring Data that will relate to a database.

What are the first steps that I should take when designing/programming this?

Set up database?

Create simple project using maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the Quick Start on Spring Boot: http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/
Spring Boot will let you fire up a Spring MVC application very quickly and easily.

If it were me, I would take this opportunity to use Gradle instead of maven (http://gradle.org/getting-started-gradle-java/).

Once you have the basic MVC setup and tested, then you can move on to setting up the database and Spring Data. You can get more information on how to setup Spring Data for Spring Boot in section 29 here: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: Why gradle over Maven? I will essentially just be using my build tool to build and declare my dependencies?

Comment: If you are familiar with Maven, Maven is find, especially if you already have Maven configured with your build tool. It's just that (opinion) Gradle is better and also does dependency management like Maven. Finally, Spring Boot integrates well with either

Comment: What are the actual advantages of gradle over maven? Which one do you find easier to use

Comment: Maven has been around a long time. The major issue with Maven it's rigidity.If you want to change src location, for example, you would have to make configuration changes in multiple places. Also, Maven is XML driven. Gradle is an actual Groovy script, letting you embed coding logic

Comment: Thanks, how do you find the two? Which one do you find better?

Comment: In Groovy or Java. Also, Gradle has strong support for Ant, so you can call any Ant task just by prefixing with ant., like ant.copy(). These are just a few. In summary Gradle is far more flexible, and powerful, yet has the exact same dependency management as Maven.In fact you can still use MavenCentral for your dependencies.

Comment: If you look a the Spring Boot quick start, you will see equivalent examples for both Maven and Gradle. Gradle has a Spring Boot plugin and is very easy to configure if you decide to give it a try.